# Uniformly sampling points in a cube using a coordinate system [C#, Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, uniform-distribution

I have a cube with six vertices of form `(x, y, z)`, in a 3D coordinate system. All information about cube is available, including vertices, edge lengths, etc.

I would like an efficient way to uniformly return `n ^ 3` points, with `n` points on each edge, something like the coordinate system itself. An image is attached (ignore the colouring) (source: [Sebastian Lague's video on marching cubes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3iI2l0ltbE&t=199s)):[image: Evenly distributed points]

I've more or less been able to implement this in Python, and I'd like a C# version.

An example of what I want:
**I've used a unit cube at the origin as an example, what I'm after is pseudocode or logic that works for any cube at any coordinates.**
More information: I'd like to have code that works for cubes in any orientation, but failing that code that works for cubes aligned with the grid but in **any position**.

Thanks to Jon Skeet for the help and clarification!

```
/*
Input:
(0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(1, 0, 1)

27 points to be generated: n = 3
3 points per edge (INCLUDING VERTICES)

Output:
(0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(0, 0.5, 0)
(0.5, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0.5)
(0.5, 0.5, 0)
(0.5, 0, 0.5)
(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
(0, 0.5, 0.5)
(1, 0.5, 0)
... etc
*/
```

**I'm using it in Unity, so answers with `Vector3` and such would work too.**

Some pseudocode:

```
// MagicPointGenerator is really what I'm after

float[][] GeneratePoints(float[][] vertices, int pointsPerEdge)
    {
        float[][] points = new float[(int)Math.Pow(pointsPerEdge, 3)][3];
        for (int i = 0; i <= pointsPerEdge; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= pointsPerEdge; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k <= pointsPerEdge; k++)
                {
                    points[i + j + k] = MagicPointGenerator(i, j, k);
                }
            }
        }
        return points;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: with 3 points per edge, you'll generate 0, 0.5, 1.0. With 4 points per edge: 0, 0.3333, 0.6666, 1.0. With 5 points per edge: 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1. Spot the pattern there, and it should be easy to code it. (If you've already done this in Python, it should be really the same algorithm...) But you *don't* want `points[i + j + k]` - that will repeat indexes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I used `np.linspace`, and I see the pattern you mean. I'm only able to extend it into 2D though, somehow I don't get how to code it in 3 Dimensions. I see the indices issue though, will redo that :)

Comment: If you can produce the sequence in *one* dimension, that's all you need - it's exactly the same pattern for each edge. (You'd apply the same formula to each of `i`, `j` and `k`.) Btw, your loop conditions should all be `<` instead of `<=`, as otherwise you'll iterate too many times. And your `MagicPointGenerator` needs to accept `pointsPerEdge` as well...

Comment: @JonSkeet I was able to do it for any number of points when I hardcoded the vertices as those of a unit cube, but I'm not able to do it dynamically... I also want it to work for cubes whose vertices are in other sections (for instance, a cube with all its 8 vertices in different octants)

Comment: Well that's a different question... you've only asked a question about a unit cube. Please restrict yourself to one question per post.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't intentional - I took a unit cube as an example, since it was the easiest to type out. I'll edit my question, thanks!

Comment: Well for "any position" can't you just translate whatever points you generate? (Likewise "any size" just requires simple scaling.) Rotation is trickier, but I'd just generate everything with respect to a unit cube and apply a transformation afterwards